# Revoke all refresh tokens of all users. Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have developed an IOS app, and I am using cognito for authentication. And the refresh token's expiry time is 1 year. But unfortunately we need all the users to re-login in app and we need to forcefully logout(revoke refresh token) every user from cognito, not only one or two users but all users form all devices.
I have researched a little bit and find that this can be done by revoking refresh token(of single user) but I can't find a solution where we can logout all users from all devices.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such option to revoke all existing tokens.

All you can do is to iterate over each and every user and revoke tokens using the [AdminUserGlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUserGlobalSignOut.html) API. You only need a username and a user pool ID to do it.